# How to set initiator in new state creation flow in Corda?

Tags: corda

I am working with Event Scheduling functionality in Corda. I have added the same in one state. Now I want to create another state automatically when the existing state gets accepted. The accept functionality is with a party, whereas the action which triggers the creation of the other state has to be with other party itself. When I try doing this, both the Initiator are same. How to set the other party as the initiator when creating the new state flow?

PS: We are following a project structure that has separate modules for contract-states and flows.

Comment: Please share some code of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to:

1. Define a flow that instead of executing any logic, simply hands off to a responder flow
2. Define a responder flow that executes the logic

Here is an example:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@SchedulableFlow
class InitiatorFlow(val counterparty: Party) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        // We send a flag message to the counterparty, causing them to start their responder flow.
        val session = initiateFlow(counterparty)
        session.send(true)
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(InitiatorFlow::class)
class InitiatedFlow(val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        // We process and discard the flag message.
        counterpartySession.receive<Boolean>()

        // TODO: Create the new state based on the acceptance.
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working.But it is showing exception while passing signers inside the flow.How to set the signers?

Comment: That sounds like an unrelated issue :) You should raise it as a separate question (though do a search here for previous answers - it may have come up before)